# Using threadlocal to bind instance of a class to a thread

Tags: java, thread-local

I have some difficulty in understanding the use of ThreadLocal in the below declaration. Does it mean, even though the instance is declared as static each thread will have it's own instance of DomainEventPublisher class

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DomainEventPublisher> instance = new ThreadLocal<DomainEventPublisher>() {
        protected DomainEventPublisher initialValue() {
            return new DomainEventPublisher();
        }
};
```

Comment: Provided you call `instance.get()` in each thread, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what `ThreadLocal` is for.

In your example, each thread will have a different instance of `DomainEventPublisher`